# Convert GeoJSON to OSM XML using Python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geojson

I know about using `ogr2ogr`, and also about the nodejs module `osm_geojson`. However, I would like to convert GeoJSON to OSM XML from Python. Is there a library which has this capability built in? Or would I have to write custom code based on the OSM XML specification?
I am processing the GeoJSON using `geopandas`, so exporting directly from `geopandas` to OSM would also work.

I have looked at the GDAL/OGR Python library.
It may be able to do what I want, but [the documentation](https://gdal.org/python/) is impenetrable. [The Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#filter-and-select-input-shapefile-to-new-output-shapefile-like-ogr2ogr-cli) has something similar to what I am looking for, but I can't quite seem to piece it together.

My code currently looks like this:

```
from osgeo import ogr
import os

# Read GeoJSON file
geojson_file = 'file.geojson'
GeoJSON_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('GeoJSON')
data = GeoJSON_driver.Open(geojson_file, 0)
layer = data.GetLayer()

# OSM file to write
osm_file = 'file.osm'
OSM_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('OSM')

# Remove output file if it already exists
if os.path.exists(osm_file):
    OSM_driver.DeleteDataSource(osm_file)

# Export data to OSM file
# This is where I'm stuck
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but from the OSM wiki https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OGR I understand that OGR allows to read, but not write. So it might not be possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Python tool ogr2osm.py available here https://github.com/roelderickx/ogr2osm.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some code to create [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) from a `geopandas` dataframe.
Note that my use case only required conversion of GeoJSON points to OSM nodes.
More complex use cases should consider adapting code from [ogr2osm](https://github.com/pnorman/ogr2osm) as mentioned in the [other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310838/convert-geojson-to-osm-xml-using-python/310935#310935).

For future reference, here is the code I used. (This assumes `geopandas` column names are valid OSM tags):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def export_geopandas_to_osm_xml(geopandas_data_frame):
    osm_root = ET.Element('osm', attrib={
        'version': '0.6',
        'generator': 'custom python script'
        })

    i = -1
    for index, row in geopandas_data_frame.iterrows():
        current_node = ET.SubElement(osm_root, 'node', attrib={
            'id': str(i),
            'lat': str(row.geometry.y),
            'lon': str(row.geometry.x),
            'changeset': 'false'})
        for column in geopandas_data_frame.loc[:, ['addr:housenumber', 'addr:street']]:
            ET.SubElement(current_node, 'tag', attrib={
                'k': column,
                'v': row[column]})
        i -= 1
    output_file = ET.ElementTree(element=osm_root)
    output_file.write('test.osm')
```